# Observe every item in a RACSequence, update observations when sequence has new items

Tags: reactive-cocoa, racsequence

This is a similar question to [an earlier question that asked about observing every item in a RACSequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17125748/observe-every-item-in-racsequence) — the correct answer was something like:

```
RACSignal *valid = [[RACSignal combineLatest:
                     [self.viewModels map:^id(ViewModel *viewModel) {
                       return RACObserve(viewModel, state);
                     }]
                    ]
                    map:^(RACTuple *states) {
                      return @([states.rac_sequence all:^BOOL(NSNumber *state) {
                        return state.unsignedIntegerValue == Completed;
                      }]);
                    }
                   ];
```

My variation on this is that I'd like to also handle the case where ViewModel instances are added/removed from the sequence as well. I can do this by invalidating a RACDisposable stored in an instance variable or property, but it would be great to do this without adding any extra state. What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer in an older post by @justin-spahr-summers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19711002/63580

Here is the version specific for my question above for posterity:

```
@weakify(self);

RACSignal *enabled = [[RACObserve(self, viewModels)
    // Map _each_ array of view models to a signal determining whether the command
    // should be enabled.
    map:^(NSArray *viewModels) {
        RACSequence *selectionSignals = [[viewModels.rac_sequence
            map:^(ViewModel *viewModel) {
                // RACObserve() implicitly retains `self`, so we need to avoid
                // a retain cycle.
                @strongify(self);

                // Observe each view model's `state` property for changes.
                return RACObserve(viewModel, state);
            }]
            // Ensure we always have one YES for the -and below.
            startWith:[RACSignal return:@YES]];

        // Sends YES whenever all of the view models are selected, NO otherwise.
        return [[RACSignal
            combineLatest:selectionSignals]
            and];
    }]
    // Then, ensure that we only subscribe to the _latest_ signal returned from
    // the block above (i.e., the observations from the latest `viewModels`).
    switchToLatest];
```